# how to make with print_r only display text in array

Tags: php, mysql

I created a members table on my database and entered the username row as user and the password row as password. Then I wrote a script that has to display the password and the username in a database. This is it:

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "root";
$password = "Hunter123";
$database = "adventure_of_dragons";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);

$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM members";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

$id = array($db_field['member_id']);  "<BR>";
$username = array($db_field['username']); "<BR>";
$password = array($db_field['password']);  "<BR>";
$rank = array($db_field['rank']);  "<BR>";

print_r($username);
print_r($password);
}

mysql_close($db_handle);

}

else {

print "Database NOT Found " . $db_handle;

}


?>
```

but when i run the code it displays this:

Array ( [0] => user ) Array ( [0] => password )

how do I make it display the text like this:

-User -Password

Please help.

Comment: Use the normal `print` function, and array key `[0]`. No wait, why are rewrapping them in an array() at all?

Comment: You don't because [**`print_r`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) was not made for that. [**`print_r`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is merely a function to help you seeing thru variables, arrays and other objects like `var_dump`.

Comment: do foreach-loop algo.

Answer (score 2):

That's simple. Just don't make arrays of them in the first place, and use regular `echo`.

*Other bugs in the code*

`print_r` is a **debug function** (just like `var_dump`), it is not used for printing out data to user.

Also, this statement: `"<BR>";` simply means nothing.
You must echo it for it to have any effect at all.

Another thing is that you've overwritten the DB connection variables in your fetching loop. It's better to use constants for this, like shown below.

---

**Here's your code, fixed**

```
<?php

define("DB_USERNAME", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "Hunter123");
define("DB_DATABASE", "adventure_of_dragons");
define("DB_SERVER", "127.0.0.1");

$db_handle = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

$db_found = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $db_handle);

if ($db_found || true) {

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM members";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

        $id = $row['member_id'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $password = $row['password'];
        $rank = $row['rank'];

        echo 'ID = ' . $id . '<br>';
        echo 'RANK = ' . $rank . '<br>';
        echo 'USERNAME = ' . $username . '<br>';
        echo 'PASSWORD = ' . $password . '<br><br>';
        // two <br>'s, so we get an empty line between users
    }

    mysql_close($db_handle);

} else {
    echo "Database NOT Found " . $db_handle;
}
```

Comment: I tried @mightypork's script but i got this error: Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\PortableApps\xampp-portable\htdocs\xampp\mysqlconnecter.php on line 23
Array

Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\PortableApps\xampp-portable\htdocs\xampp\mysqlconnecter.php on line 24
Array

Comment: idk what you did, but I forgot to remove two of the extra brackets. Try this new version.

Comment: and what if i have more then one username or password?

Comment: I found yet another bug in your code, the post is now updated. Removed a variable name clash.

Comment: tried it and this is the output: '; echo 'RANK = ' . $rank . '
'; echo 'USERNAME = ' . $username . '
'; echo 'PASSWORD = ' . $password . '

'; } mysql_close($db_handle); } else { echo "Database NOT Found " . $db_handle; }

Comment: @FireRaven101 Just because you're **unable to copy a piece of code**, it doesn't mean the code is broken. I tried it and it runs perfectly.